# Increase the no of xticks on axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

[Here is the output of pro.head(20)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6gKy.png)[image: this is my output screen]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

pro=pd.read_excel("biotech.xlsx")

#the head of the file is given here

#Sample,    Sample ID,  Total No,   Location,   Dil CFU per ml.


plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

sns.barplot(pro["Sample"],pro["CFU per ml"],hue=pro["Location"],dodge=False)
```

while executing the above line,

I got the plot with 8 points on x axis which is supposed to be 9.

Here, the problem is the Soil (Sample) in two places (Mathikettan and Anamudi) has been combined to one set and displayed

What should i do now for getting a clear plot of this???

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this with `catplot`;

```
g = sns.catplot(
    x=pro["Sample"], y=pro["CFU per ml"], 
    hue=pro["Location"], col="Location",
    data=pro, kind="bar", height=4, aspect=.7)
```

Depending on how you want to compare (sample by location) or locations per sample you can swap them around.

You can find the docs [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot).

Comment: no, its not working.Again it had combined in the soil bar. Please tell any other method..thanks for your immediate response.

Comment: Can you share the structure of the `pro` data? Something like `pro.head(20)` to get an idea of how it looks.

Comment: as you have requested, i have attached my output for pro.head(20).thank you for your response